# How to display all files from a folder?

Tags: php, html, email, web

This is my code.

```
$mail = "You don't have any mail.";
                    
$maildir = "mial/";

    if (!empty($maildir)) {
                        
    if ($mailopen = opendir($maildir)) {
        while (false !== ($mailread = readdir($mailopen))) {
        if ($mailread != '.' && $mailread != '..') {
        $mail = "|  $mailread"; }}}
                        
}
```

When I echo $mail, it just shows one item at a time.
How do I make it display all the files in the directory?

Something like this

email 1
email 2
etc.

Comment: You're overwriting `$mail` each time. use `.=` rather than `=` to append the `$mailread` values instead.

Comment: if you want to echo all files, you must echo inside the `if($mailread != ...){ $mail = "|  $mailread"; echo $mail; }` body.

Comment: @berend How can I echo the files outside the body?

Comment: You are inconsistent with your use of the terms "directory" and "folder" which is a Windows concept and not the same thing.

Comment: if you'd like to concatenate the output, use `$mail .= ...` as per comment @Don'tPanic. You can then output the resulting string outside the body using `echo $mail;`.

Comment: @berend Thanks, but now it also gives me an error saying that $mail is undefined. How do I fix that?

Comment: just define it outside the `while` loop: `$mail = "";`